# Continue with next line execution after subprocess run in python

Tags: python, subprocess

Below is the lines of code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run('"C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"')
    print("hiiiiii")
```

In this case notepad.exe is opened , but print("hiiiiiii) is not executed until i close notepad.exe
In my case i want to have the print("hiiiiii") to be executed after notepad.exe is opened

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.run()` blocks the main process, `Popen()` instead

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.Popen('"C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"')
    print("hiiiiii")
```

Comment: Its working fine with Popen() Thanks